# How to change the position of Compass on MapView - Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a MapView and I need to change the position of the compass since I need the top space for my header overlay.

Notice that the compass is under the header overlay. I need to move it slightly below.

[image]

Comment: which API version are you using? how are you setting up the map and overlays?

Answer (score 0):

The only way seems to be to derive my own class from MyLocationOverlay.

```
Override drawCompass();
```

Basically manipulate the Canvas object, call super.drawCompass() to draw the compass at your new location. Restore the Canvas to how you found it.